# Question Mark on Lock Screen

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I've updated my S3 Mini, and now i have a question mark on my lock screen, it's right below the time, and right to the date, and above the message "discharging x%"

What is this question mark?

[image: screenshot of S3 mini lockscreen with orange question mark next to the date display]

Comment: Would it be possible to get a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, how can i do it? :( i've tryed home+power button but i guess it doesn't works on lock screen

Comment: It does work on my galaxy S3 running JB, though you have to hold it for a few seconds.  Alternatively, there's a setting in settings->motion that will allow you to trigger a screenshot by swiping your palm across the screen.

Comment: i don't have that menu, but have another one that worked :)

Comment: Does the question mark do anything if you touch it, swipe across it, or drag the unlocker up to it?

Comment: I had this on my Nexus 4 for a while I believe it happened when it was unable to update weather data or something (That's the weather widget - or it was for me)

Comment: It was something about the weather in the clock.

thank you all